# MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException after updated the chrome driver to 80

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

My Test scripts are working in chrome browser 78 with chromedriver 78. with selenium 3.141.59

Now we updated the browser version to 80 and chromedriver to 80, we are using selenium 3.141.59.

In my test scripts we used actions class to move objects to destination. we are moving objects based on coordinates.
Now we are getting "MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException" exception while moving objects with coordinates.

Below is my reusable method. We are using Chrome 80. we are passing x,y parameters values as 0,0.

```
public void dragAndDropcomponentToFormEditor(WebElement sourceEle, WebElement desEle, int x,int y) {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")){
        ReusableMethods.jsScrollToWebElement(sourceEle);
        action.clickAndHold(sourceEle).moveToElement(desEle,-((desEle.getSize().getWidth()/2)-100),-((desEle.getSize().getHeight()/2)-50)).release().perform();
        }else{
            action.clickAndHold(sourceEle).moveToElement(desEle, x, y).release().perform();
        }
        LOGGER.info("dragged a component into form editor - "+sourceEle.toString());
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is very difficult identity proper coordinates for each release of chrome driver. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer without code samples and html structure of elements. Please read [mcve] and edit post accordingly